# Filter nodes with current site language

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, filtering

I`m using Views with Views OR module, and i want to filter biblio publications according to this scheme:

```
Current Site Language: English
Biblio Publication Language(not node translation language): English
== OR
Current Site Language: Russian
Biblio Publication Language(not node translation language): English
== OR
Current Site Language: Russian
Biblio Publication Language(not node translation language): Russian
```

But I cannot find appropriate filter to indicate current site language.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Views filter:

Node translation: Language - Current user's language (optionally select "No language" as well)

Comment: AFAIK this applies only to registered user`s. But as registered user I can view site with both languages.

Comment: Current user's language is a misleading name. It actually goes through the language options list configured, which includes more than just user preference. Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2037979